# Programatically construct netconf edit-config request

Tags: xml, go, ietf-netmod-yang, ietf-netconf

I am trying to programatically construct netconf edit-config request for a yang schema config object. Currently I am constructing this xml string manually. Is there a way I can do this programatically? I am using golang

for example, I am trying to send edit-config request for bgp config element as defined in the schema bgp-config.yang:

```
module bgp-config {
    namespace "http://exnet.com/bgp-config";
    prefix bgp-config;
    import ietf-inet-types { prefix inet; }
    import tailf-common { prefix tailf; }
    import ietf-yang-types { prefix yang; }
    import ietf-bgp-types { prefix bgp-types; }
    import ietf-bgp-multiprotocol { prefix bgp-mp; }
    import openconfig-routing-policy { prefix rpol; }
    import myietf-routing {prefix rt;}
    revision "2016-04-07" {
    description "Revisied on 2016-04-07.";
    }
    augment "/rt:router"
    {
 list bgp {
     //presence "Container for BGP protocol hierarchy";
     //tailf:cli-add-mode;
     tailf:info "Top-level configuration and state for the BGP router";
     tailf:cli-full-no;
     tailf:cli-suppress-list-no;
     key "local-as";
     max-elements 1;
     description
         "Top-level configuration and state for the BGP router";
     uses bgp_config;
     uses bgp-graceful-restart;
     uses bgp-mp:bgp-route-selection-options;
     //tailf:cli-suppress-no;
     container afi-safis {
         tailf:cli-drop-node-name;
         description
             "Address family specific configuration";
         uses bgp-mp:bgp-common-afi-safi-list;
     }

          }
}
```

I have this code snippet to send edit-config request to the netconf server for the bgp config element:

```
var s *netconf.Session 
localas := 888 
xmlstr := `<edit-config>
        <target><candidate/></target>
         <config>
         <router xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:yang:ietf-routing">
         <bgp xmlns="http://exnet.com/bgp-config">
         <local-as>` + strconv.Itoa(localas) + `</local-as>
         </bgp>
      </router>
     </config>
    </edit-config>`
 NetConfSendRPC(s, xmlstr)
 xmlstr = "<commit/>"
 NetConfSendRPC(s, xmlstr)
 s.Close()
```

My question is on the lines of how I can programatically construct the xml string to send edit-config for all the config elements. The first step would be to generate xml tagged go structs from the yang schema (this is where I need help/pointers) and then I can use xml marshal methods to construct the request. Any suggestions for the first step would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Can you add the XML file that you want to construct programatically?

Comment: apologies for the lack of details, I have added the snippets above. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2):

1. Map the XML document to tagged structs.
2. Create a struct that represents the configuration you desire.
3. Marshal the struct using [`xml.MarshalIndent`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/#MarshalIndent) (see example).

See also https://github.com/Juniper/go-netconf

Comment: thanks for the pointers! I am stuck at the first step - basically to generate xml tagged go structs from yang schema.